# How to add equirectangular environment map to gltf model in A-Frame?

Tags: three.js, aframe, gltf

When importing a gltf object into an a-frame scene I'd like to set an equirectangular environment map for that object to influence its reflections. I'd like to use the same img DOM id reference as I used in the sky entity. How can I do that?

For example, I'd like to be able to specify code such as this:
`<a-entity gltf-model="#model-file" env-map="#sky"> </a-entity>`

I found a cubemap version of this by @donmccurdy but looking for equirectangular instead and also a mechanism to use an already loaded image texture.
https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/misc#cube-env-map

Answer (score 2):

See this answer:
[Aframe gltf-model demo with envmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59625510/aframe-gltf-model-demo-with-envmap/59628444#59628444)

Another option for the future, investigate `scene.environment` threejs which may apply the same environment map automatically to all objects with supported materials.